# Error creating bitmap VB

Tags: vb.net, bitmap

I am currently loading an image from a path in a Bitmap object.
But I get the following error:

**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

In this line:

```
Dim myBitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(paginasFolder)
myBitmap.SetResolution(300, 300)


                                myBitmap.Save(strReplaceName & tercero & "m.tif", tiffEncoder, eps)
                                myBitmap.Dispose()
```

any suggestions?

Comment: if `paginasFolder` is not a valid file name of a valid image file, `myBitmap` will be nothing.

Comment: Paginasfolder is a string that comes from ForEach. I am printing in the log that variable and is not null. I have no idea of this error.